# Value whitelist using strong parameters in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

Is it possible to use strong parameters to ensure that an attribute will be filtered with a whitelist of possible values?

For example, I have a parameter age that I want to ensure that can only have this values [10,20,30,40,50]. Is it possible to use the strong parameters logic to ensure that?

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with validations?

Comment: you can see more on strong parameters here http://blog.trackets.com/2013/08/17/strong-parameters-by-example.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quick answer**

No! [Strong parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) only let you to filter keys from a hash regardless of the value they have.

**Long answer**

No! But as it was pointed out in comments, your best solution is to use [validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#inclusion):

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :value, inclusion: { in: [1,2,3] }
end
```