# Rails 4 parameters; how to whitelist a param to a set of values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, security, controllers

I have already read some posts, such as [Value whitelist using strong parameters in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541432), but it's not quite what I need.

I have a controller which takes an ID and loads a model. It also optionally takes a query string param (`style`) which can be one of 3 values, `small`, `medium` or `large`. This is passed to a method on the model which uses it to fetch an attached image (using paperclip). I noticed that if I pass an invalid param (eg `style=wibble`), then I get a 400 error and a notice that the internal file path doesn't exist. Brakeman also notes this as a security issue...

```
def show
  style = params[:style] || :medium

  thing = Model.find(params[:id])

  path = "#{Rails.root}/public#{thing.image_url(style)}"
  content_type = thing.image.content_type || 'image/png'
  send_file path, type: content_type, disposition: 'inline'
end
```

We use [ActionController Parameters](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) elsewhere to great effect; but I cannot see how that could "whitelist" a parameters options? Everywhere I have seen says to use a model validator, but that's assuming I'm submitting a parameter to update a model, which I am not.

I'm aware I could do something like:

```
return head :not_found unless %w(small medium large).include? style
```

Is this the best way?

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a gem that extends `ActionController::Parameters` for exactly this purpose: whitelisting parameter values. It's simple and lightweight. You would use it like this:

```
def model_params
  params.require(:model).permit(:style, :other_attribute).allow(style: %w[small medium large])
end
```

Hope you find it useful

https://github.com/msimonborg/allowable

Comment: @Nick Thanks! : )

Comment: @m.simonborg good work! Although, I don't think that `{ 'a' => 1 }.allow(a: 1)` should work, your code is disregarding the fact that the hash is a regular Hash or HashWithIndifferentAccess. Also, `{ a: 1, 'a' => 2 }.allow(a: [1,2])` would allow both keys and I have no way to restrict this based on the key's type. (I have not tested it, just read the source code)

Comment: @MrYoshiji thanks, that's very good feedback. I developed it with `ActionController::Parameters` in mind, so the implementation for that is probably not the best implementation for `Hash`. I think a separate implementation for `Hash` in a separate module will address those valid issues

Comment: @MrYoshiji thanks again for raising the issue, pushed those changes so key types are respected in `Hash`

Comment: @m.simonborg thank you for this tool, I will probably use it in my next project!

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to define a Constant white-listing all the valid `style` values (I would argue that `size_type` is a more explicit name). (Watch out for the Symbol / String comparisons).

Then, you either return a 404 if the `params[:style]` is not included in the white-listed values OR you fallback to `'medium'`:

```
style = Model::AVAILABLE_SIZE_TYPES.include?(params[:style]) ? params[:style] || Model::AVAILABLE_SIZE_TYPES.first
```

Personally, I don't like fallbacks for user's input. They did something wrong (manipulated the URL, changed a value in a form, etc), they deserve to get an error page.

I implied the constant is defined in the Model, but it should not be there as it is not related to the business logic but related to the display of the Model. If you have a ModelDecorator, define it there.

Comment: Going along with this, [looks like](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#post-processing) using paper clip the model is possibly setup like `has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { thumb: ["32x32#", :png] }` so I'd probably suggest using the constant there as well `AVAILABLE_SIZE_TYPES = { thumb: ["32x32#", :png] }` `has_attached_file :avatar, styles: AVAILABLE_SIZE_TYPES` and then `Model::AVAILABLE_SIZE_TYPES.has_key?(params[:style])` (again watch string/symbols)...single source of truth...if you added `:tiny` later, it's already updated.

Comment: Extending what @SimpleLime said: you can have one constant, let's say `IMAGE_CONFIGURATIONS = { small: ['32x32#', :png] }.freeze` and then define `AVAILABLE_SIZE_TYPES = IMAGE_CONFIGURATIONS.keys` or even have an `ImageConfiguration` object (see part "Extracting Value Objects" of the following excellent article https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/decoupling-rails-components)